# getting null value in dropdownlist on rowdatabound event using gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting error :-`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

When I want to bind the data into `dropdownlist` this will give me error.
Here is my code:

```
protected void EventRequirementGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         DropDownList ddllist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("modeldropdownlist");

         ddllist.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "exammode").ToString();               
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we have to guess what line the error occurred on?  I'm guessing FindControl is returning null.

Comment: i think You are geeting null value in ddllist.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
protected void EventRequirementGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {                     
           DropDownList ddllist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("modeldropdownlist");
           ddllist.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "exammode").ToString();               
    }
}
```

**(Or)**

```
 protected void EventRequirementGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
           if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {            
               DropDownList ddllist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("modeldropdownlist");
               ddllist.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "exammode").ToString();               
            }
         }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use PreRender event of GridView to access controls from EditItemTemplate like:

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if (GridView1.EditIndex != -1) 
  {
     //Just changed the index of cells based on your requirements
     DropDownList ddllist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("modeldropdownlist");
     ddllist.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "exammode").ToString();              
  }
}
```